# Boxplot slightly moving depentend on upper whisker

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, boxplot

I created a few boxplots which should align with each other. I noticed that one of the boxplots, the second one, is slightly moving to the left if the upper whisker is "**5**". This doesn't happen if, e.g. the upper whisker is 4.99. Any ideas why this happens and how to solve it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                ytick={1},
                yticklabel style={text width=2.0cm, align=right},
                yticklabels={plot\\one},
                width=(\textwidth-1.0cm),
                height=2.7cm,
                ybar,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                ]
                \addplot+[boxplot,  draw=black,
                boxplot prepared={
                    median=50,
                    upper quartile=50,
                    lower quartile=49,
                    upper whisker=56,
                    lower whisker=40
                }, 
                ] coordinates {};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                ytick={1},
                % xmin = 2.5,
                yticklabel style={text width=2.0cm, align=right},
                yticklabels={plot\\two},
                width=(\textwidth-1.0cm),
                height=2.7cm,
                ybar,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                ]
                \addplot+[boxplot, draw=black,
                boxplot prepared={
                    median=4,
                    upper quartile=4,
                    lower quartile=3,
                    upper whisker=5, %4.99 --> not moving to the left
                    lower whisker=3
                },
                ] coordinates {};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                ytick={1},
                yticklabel style={text width=2.0cm, align=right},
                yticklabels={plot\\three},
                width=(\textwidth-1.0cm),
                height=2.7cm,
                ybar,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                ]
                \addplot+[boxplot, draw=black,
                boxplot prepared={
                    median=2,
                    upper quartile=3,
                    lower quartile=2,
                    upper whisker=7,
                    lower whisker=1
                },
                ] coordinates {};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{todo}  
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

// EDIT:
One solution for this minimal expample is to put a min value, e.g. `xmin = 2.5,` into the header of the plot. The `xmax` value again ruins the alignment. It also help in my big tex-document but still isn't aligned perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is the "outside" xtick 5.2. You could suppress the effect by setting the style to overlay (but then you will have to add space below the plot), of you could set the xtick explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                ytick={1},
                yticklabel style={text width=2.0cm, align=right},
                yticklabels={plot\\one},
                width=(\textwidth-1.0cm),
                height=2.7cm,
                ybar,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                ]
                \addplot+[boxplot,  draw=black,
                boxplot prepared={
                    median=50,
                    upper quartile=50,
                    lower quartile=49,
                    upper whisker=56,
                    lower whisker=40
                },
                ] coordinates {};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                ytick={1},
                % xmin = 2.5,
                yticklabel style={text width=2.0cm, align=right},
                yticklabels={plot\\two},
                width=(\textwidth-1.0cm),
                height=2.7cm,
                ybar,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                %xticklabel style={overlay},   %also possible             
                xtick={3,3.2,...,5} %<------
                ]
                \addplot+[boxplot, draw=black,
                boxplot prepared={
                    median=4,
                    upper quartile=4,
                    lower quartile=3,
                    upper whisker=5, %4.99 --> not moving to the left
                    lower whisker=3
                },
                ] coordinates {};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                ytick={1},
                yticklabel style={text width=2.0cm, align=right},
                yticklabels={plot\\three},
                width=(\textwidth-1.0cm),
                height=2.7cm,
                ybar,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                ]
                \addplot+[boxplot, draw=black,
                boxplot prepared={
                    median=2,
                    upper quartile=3,
                    lower quartile=2,
                    upper whisker=7,
                    lower whisker=1
                },
                ] coordinates {};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{todo}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]